# Comparing SQL Server table using hashbytes slower than without

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 LocalDB.

A client wants me to compare 2 tables which consist each (believe it or not) out of 200 (!) columns of `nvarchar(max)` values. There are no indexes and there are no unique keys.

I have googled my way to find (http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx) and the method works. However using 200 columns in the union all / group by expression is a little bit slow.

The query looks like this

```
SELECT 
    MIN(TableName) as TableName , header1, header2, header3, header....
INTO RESULTS  
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        'table1' as TableName, table1.header1, table1.header2, table1.header3, table1.header...
     FROM table1 

     UNION ALL 

     SELECT 
         'table2' as TableName , table2.header1, table2.header2, table2.header3, table2.header...
    ) tmp 
GROUP BY 
    header1, header2, header3, header...
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = 1
```

[image: Excecution Plan of first query]

My thought was to calculate the hashbyte values for any row as described here (http://www.bidn.com/blogs/TomLannen/bidn-blog/2265/using-hashbytes-to-compare-columns) and save it in an extra column (one more doesn't hurt in this case :-) ). The hashbytes themselves are calculated very fast but when I run my query afterwards using only the hashbyte value in my union all / group by /having clause the query is very much slower. Instead of about 25 seconds in the first case it runs about 15 minutes!

The second query looks like this (with compareHash being the inserted hashbyte column):

```
SELECT 
    MIN(TableName) as TableName, compareHash 
INTO RESULTS  
FROM 
   (SELECT 
       'table1' as TableName , compareHash 
    FROM table1 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
       'table2' as TableName , compareHash 
    FROM table2) tmp 
GROUP BY 
    compareHash 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = 1
```

[image: Execution Plan for second query]
I would have expected the exact opposite. Can anybody think about a reason for this behaviour?

Best regards
Sebastian

Comment: It would help to see the query you're executing against the new hash column.  It would also help to know if you've created a new index that includes the hash column.

Comment: Michael: I have updated it in the question. I have not created an index.

Comment: The queries look okay, so I'd recommend comparing the execution plan generated for each query and copying a screenshot of the plans into your question.  The plans may reveal some optimization sql server can perform in the first query and not the second.

Comment: Michael: I have made screenshots of the execution plan, does this give you a hint?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the query plans, you'll notice that significantly fewer rows (judging by the thickness of the arrows) are returned by the second query.

This leads me to wonder if you've correctly populated the `compareHash` column.  I.e. if all 200 columns were correctly included in the hash.

If anything, I would expect the second query to return *more* rows, since hashing the character data will force the comparison to be case-sensitive. The default collation in sql server would perform a case-insensitive comparison for your first query over the varchar values.

While this has more to do with correctness, you usually want to compare approaches that yield the same answer when comparing performance.

---

Correctness aside, another observation is that in the first query, the data is sorted and then a streaming aggregate is applied.  In the second query, a hash table is built and the second table is used to probe the hash table.  You could try to force the sorted streaming aggregate plan in the second query by adding `OPTION (ORDER GROUP)` at the end of your query and see if that changes execution time, but I doubt it will improve it.

My guess is that the original varchar data has some natural ordering that sql server is taking advantage of in the first query.

If you're open to creating an index on the `compareHash` columns, you'll probably see significant performance gains in the second query since it'll use a merge-join.

Comment: Michael: thank you very much for your hints, unfortunately I couldn't solve the problem yet. "Option(Order group)" had no effect but what I don't understand at all: adding an index on the compareHash column has no effect either. This feels plain wrong.